# How to compare an array with another element with javascript vanilla

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to do a simple check using the if statement, I'm comparing an element with an array using this function, I want to show the result based on the conditions but when a run the function it didn't execute the first if, even if it equal to one of the elements in the array it goes to the second statement.

```
function TalkTheTalk(msg) {

    const talk = +msg; 

    const greetings = ["I'm good", "I'm fine", "I'm Ok"];

    greetings.map((greeting)=> {
        if(greeting === talk) {
            MessageEl.innerHTML = '<div> Im so happy to hear that! what can i do for you today ! </div>';
        }
        else if (greeting !== talk) {
            MessageEl.innerHTML = '<div>Sorry I didnt hear !Would you Repeat</div>';
        }
        else {
            MessageEl.innerHTML = '<div>Would you repeat</div>';
        }
        
    });
}
```

Comment: The [Unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) in `+msg` will convert it to a number and `talk` is most likely `NaN`. So, the strict equality `===` will never be true. Why do you have the `+` operator there? Is that a typo?

Comment: I put it there because I have another function to compare numbers. but I forget to remove it from this function. Thank you guys for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function TalkTheTalk(msg) {

    // const talk = +msg; This makes it a NaN
    const talk = msg; 

    const greetings = ["I'm good", "I'm fine", "I'm Ok"];

    // greetings.map((greeting)=> { map means convert each one to something else, not suitable
    const result greetings.find((greeting)=> {
        return greeting === talk
    });

    if (result) {
        MessageEl.innerHTML = '<div> Im so happy to hear that! what can i do for you today ! </div>';
    } else {
        MessageEl.innerHTML = '<div>Sorry I didnt hear !Would you Repeat</div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript unary operator + is for Numbers, not for strings.

```js
console.log(+'hello'); // NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your code.
First is `const talk = +msg;`
it makes `greeting === talk` will never be true.
And second is map function.
So the last loop condition will be render.
I think you should do like this.

```js
function TalkTheTalk(msg) {

    const talk = msg; 
    var MessageEl = document.getElementById("message");
    console.log(talk);
    var heargreeting = false

    const greetings = ["I'm good", "I'm fine", "I'm Ok"];

    greetings.map((greeting)=> {
        if(greeting === talk) {
           heargreeting = true;
        }
        else if (greeting !== talk) {
            MessageEl.innerHTML = '<div>Sorry I didnt hear !Would you Repeat</div>';
        }
        else {
            MessageEl.innerHTML = '<div>Would you repeat</div>';
        }
        
    });
    if(heargreeting)
    {
        MessageEl.innerHTML = '<div> Im so happy to hear that! what can i do for you today ! </div>';
    }
}

TalkTheTalk("I'm good");
```

```html
<div id="message"></div>
```